# FTP write character NUL on server arq mainframe?

Tags: java, ftp, mainframe

I am trying to write one file via FTP the server that I am using is the mainframe architecture, at the end of the file wrote character NUL(or empty) If I testing on other servers for example windows this runs fine. I try to write different end line example CR, CRLF, LF and is the same result, even in the input only write "hello" and added on finally nul. The extensions of the file is.FTP
Example:
hello**NULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNUL**

```
public FTPUploader(String host, String user, String pwd, String contentFile, String fileName) throws Exception{
ftp = new FTPClient();
ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
int reply;
ftp.connect(host);
reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
    ftp.disconnect();
    throw new Exception("Exception in connecting to FTP Server");
}
ftp.login(user, pwd);
ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
ftp.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

String remotePath = fileName;   

FTPFile[] remoteFiles = ftp.listFiles(remotePath);
System.out.println(contentFile);
/*If exist the file this will an append*/
if (remoteFiles.length > 0)
{
    contentFile = "\n" + contentFile;
    System.out.println(contentFile);
    InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(contentFile.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    this.ftp.appendFile(remotePath, targetStream);
    System.out.println("File " + remoteFiles[0].getName() + " exists"); 
}
else/*If no exist the file this will an append*/
{
    System.out.println(contentFile);
    InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(contentFile.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    this.ftp.storeFile(remotePath, targetStream);
    System.out.println("File " + remotePath + " does not exists");
}
```

}

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your text. It will be easier to follow and you will get more attention.

Answer (score 0):

Use the parameter LOCSITE TRAILINGBLANKS if from mainframe to other server. This will keep the blanks at the end of records.

Comment: //FTPSTP1  EXEC PGM=FTP                                    
//SYSTCPD  DD  .. 
//SYSFTPD  DD  ..                                
//SYSPRINT DD  SYSOUT=*                               
//OUTPUT   DD  SYSOUT=*                                                                    
//INPUT    DD  *                                      
192.168.1.0                                     
userid                                        
password                                               
locsite trailingblanks                                         
put 'zos.dataset' server.file

Comment: For controlling trailing space, in ftp we have command locsite trail and notrail but I ... in Java with the help of trim(). no does not remove trailing blank characters.